# r-combinations with repetition allowed - How to calculate $X_{\geq y}$?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, combinations

I'm working on solving some combination word problems for class, but my textbook doesn't explain how to calculate $\geq$ combinations.

For example, a bakery produces 6 kinds of pastry, one is eclairs, how many different selections of 20 pastries contain at most 2 eclairs if there are 20 of each other kind.

I know that this is equal to $N(T) - N(E_{\geq 3})$

$N(T) = 53130$

But I don't know how to calculate $N(E_{\geq 3})$.  What is the method for doing this?

Comment: So there are total 120 pastries ??

Comment: Sorry, just edited it so it's correct.  How many different selections of 20 pastries contain at most 2 eclairs if there are 20 of each other kind.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is not very clear, but working backwards from your $N(T)= 53130$, I take it to be a stars and bars question.

The way to take care of the restriction is to pre-place 3 eclairs, place 17 more pastries selected of all 6 kinds using stars and bars, and exclude all such.

Thus selections to be excluded are $\binom{17+6-1}{6-1}$

Proceed....

Answer (score 0):

A general way to solve such problems is through generating functions. Using $z$ to count the number of each, and as you are asked for 20 in all and there are 20 of each, we can simplify our problem by considering there are infinite of each. The restrictions then translate into the following generating functions:

**For eclairs:** At most 2

$\begin{align}
1 + z + z^2
  = \frac{1 - z^3}{1 - z}
\end{align}$

**For each other type:** No restrictions

$\begin{align}
1 + z + z^2 + \dotsb
  = \frac{1}{1 - z}
\end{align}$

**In all:** We want the coefficient of $z^{20}$ in the product of the above:

$\begin{align}
[z^{20}] \frac{1 - z^3}{1 - z} \cdot \left( \frac{1}{1 - z} \right)^5
  &= [z^{20}] \frac{1 - z^3}{(1 - z)^6} \\
  &= [z^{20}] (1 - z^3) \sum_{k \ge 0} (-1)^k \binom{-6}{k} z^k \\
  &= [z^{20}] (1 - z^3) \sum_{k \ge 0} \binom{k + 6 - 1}{6 - 1} z^k \\
  &= \left( [z^{20}] - [z^{17}] \right)
       \sum_{k \ge 0} \binom{k + 5}{5} z^k \\
  &= \binom{20 + 5}{5} - \binom{17 + 5}{5} \\
  &= 26796
\end{align}$